# jquery.validate validation for non active tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-tabs

I've a form which uses [jQuery UI based tab](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) to organize different fields. I'm using [jquery.validate.min.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js) for validation. For example some fields have class = "required" which informs the plugin for required field validation. Finally, before form submit I validate the form to ensure all inputs are correct. A simple usage like -

```
HTML

...
<input type="text" class = "required" ...

SCRIPT

...
$("#frmClaim").validate();//to initilize validation
...
$('#frmClaim').submit(function () {            
             if($(this).valid())
                { ... }
         });
...
```

The issue I'm facing is that if I'm on tab 3 and there's a "required" field on tab 2 which the user has not populated, the validation is NOT performed. The validation triggers only for the fields which are visible - that is the active. Is this possible or am I missing something?

For now, on submit I manually activate each tab, perform .valid and proceed. Is there a better work around?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Initialize validation like this to validate your hidden fields

```
$("#frmClaim").validate( 
 { ignore: [] }
);
```

Comment: Glad that got me half way thru. But as expected it didn't set focus to the tab which had error so I believe I'm gonna have to manually check and set it. More then this would be over-expectation.

Comment: Reading the project site, this is due to hidden elements being ignored by default from 1.9. https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/279

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that worked for me. The idea is to iterate for all tabs, calling validate on the form and stop when you find an invalid tab or submit the form if there is no invalid fields.

```
$("#my_form").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form, evt) {
            var f = $(form);
            var tab = $("#my_tab_id");
            var tabs_count = tab.children('ul').children('li').length;
            var active = tab.tabs('option', 'active');
            var invalid = false;
            var validated = 0;

            while (validated < tabs_count && !invalid) {
                if (!f.valid()) {
                    invalid = true;
                    break;
                }

                active++;
                active = active % tabs_count;
                tab.tabs('option', 'active', active);

                validated++;
            }

            if (!invalid)
                form.submit();
            else
                evt.preventDefault();
        },
        rules: {
            ...
        },
        messages: {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function saveStuff() {

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#FORMID');

    var data = {};

    var anyError = false;

    var _frm = $('#FORMID');

    var _validator = _frm.data('validator');
    _validator.settings.ignore = "";

    _frm.find('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
        if (!_validator.element(this)) {
            anyError = true;
        }
    });

    if (anyError) {
        return false;
    }

    //SAVE DATA CODE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
var frmCl=$("#frmClaim").validate();//to initilize validation
...
$('#frmClaim').submit(function () { 
     if($(frmCl).valid())
         { ... }
});
```

Comment: are you sure this is what you mean?  It doesn't work.  frmCl is a reference to the validator, calling $(frmCl).valid() just throws an error.